A uniform way to call a member function from both explicit and implicit object member functions
TL;DR
Is there a way to have the same code snippet (macro), that calls a given member function from another member functions, which might have both explicit or implicit object parameters? Something like this:
if constexpr (/* this is defined */) {
  this->func();
} else {
  self.func();
}

Details and context
There is an Explicit object parameter (deducing this) feature from C++23 and it works great. We have logging macros in our code base and they work great. But when I try to combine the two, everything falls apart.
If you want to log from a class, you need to inherit it from the base class which looks more or less like this:
class LoggableComponent {
public:
    LoggableComponent(std::string logger_name) : logger_name_(std::move(logger_name)) {}

    const std::string& get_current_logger_name() const {
        return logger_name_;
    }

private:
    std::string logger_name_;
};

Then you can use a macro that looks like this:
#define LOG() std::cout << '[' << get_current_logger_name() << "] "

In the following way:
class A : public LoggableComponent {
public:
    A() : LoggableComponent("A") {}

    void foo() {
        LOG() << "foo()\n";
    }

    void bar() {
        LOG() << "bar()\n";
    }
};

This is of course an over-simplification of the actual approach, which allows to log with different levels, does some pretty formatting, redirects output to multiple backends, uses clever non-blocking synchronisation among multiple threads etc. But it should give you the idea of the general motivation.
And it works great: https://godbolt.org/z/qh7P9169Y
But this won't work for functions with explicit object parameter:
    void bar(this auto&& self) {
        LOG() << "bar()\n";  // error: call to non-static member function without an object argument
    }

Fair enough, instead of just get_current_logger_name() we need to write self.get_current_logger_name() in this context. But we really do want to use exactly the same LOG macro. And, believe me, you cannot replace the real-world LOG macro with anything else, it has to be a macro.
Ok, let's assume that explicit object parameter is always called self (sounds like a reasonable assumption) and simply check for it. The macro would look like this (omitting \ at the end of the lines to reduce visual noise):
#define LOG() 
  {
    std::string logger_name;
    if constexpr (requires { { self.get_current_logger_name() } -> std::convertible_to<std::string>; }) {
      logger_name = self.get_current_logger_name();
    } else {
      logger_name = get_current_logger_name();
    }
    std::cout << '[' << logger_name << "] ";
  }
  std::cout

Unfortunately, this does not work, because compiler does not allow to mention get_current_logger_name() or this->get_current_logger_name() in the else branch of a constexpr if even if it is never taken.
The standard says (https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.this#3):

It [this keyword] shall not appear within the declaration of either a static member function or an explicit object member function of the current class

Ok, seems like there is no way we can ever mention this or unqualified get_current_logger_name in the body of an explicit object member function. Let's go the other way around, and try to dance around self.
Let's do a little hack. Add a stub like this:
namespace detail {
  int self;
};

And add some dispatching code in LoggableComponent class:
protected:
    template<std::derived_from<LoggableComponent> T>
    static const std::string& get_current_logger_name_impl(const T& self) {
        return self.get_current_logger_name();
    }
    template<class T> 
    const std::string& get_current_logger_name_impl(const T&) const {
        return get_current_logger_name();
    }

Now change the macro to this:
#define LOG() { using namespace detail; std::cout << '[' << get_current_logger_name_impl(self) << "] "; } std::cout

Hooray, it works for both functions now! It even works if we have a self variable in foo() or a self member in A.
However, it fails in a particular case when there is a member function A::self():
<source>:36:9: error: reference to non-static member function must be called; did you mean to call it with no arguments?
   36 |         LOG() << "foo()\n";
      |         ^~~~~
<source>:29:90: note: expanded from macro 'LOG'
   29 | #define LOG() { using namespace detail; std::cout << '[' << get_current_logger_name_impl(self) << "] "; } std::cout
      |                                                                                          ^~~~

And similarly to mentioning this in an explicit object member function, it seems like there is no way to mention a member function without calling it (or prepending it with A::).
Now I'm stuck. Here is how far I've got: https://godbolt.org/z/Ejv94foE5
Any ideas on how to tackle this? Remember the rules:

LOG should be a macro without parameters
You can change implementations of LOG and LoggableComponent as you want, but you cannot touch A
User should still be able to do reasonable stuff with their code, like having self variables and functions.


Why LOG should be a MACRO and not a regular function from LoggableComponent?

I think the main reason is that it expands to something like if (logger_level >= backend_level) , so the whole expression won't even be evaluated for e.g. DEBUG logs when we only printing INFO logs.

I'm not sure if this will help, but there is std::invoke which is kind of a stopgap until/if the language gets UFCS.

Looked at it, was not able to benefit from it ‍♂️

@Mikhail You can make it work with std::invoke using the trick I used/invented. In particular, you just need to create local variables called self in the implicit member function and then use self in the macro as shown in this answer

Two problems: 1. Using macros is not a good idea(yes I do preach). 2. You want a parameter in your function call, either this or self and must specify it explicitly. There are a bunch of solutions, but they all need that extra object.

There are two ways to solve this. One is with std::invoke and the other without it. Also both of these require minimal changes to A.
Method 1
One workaround is to use std::invoke. To make this work, we'll need to define a local variable called self in the implicit member functions as shown below:
#define LOG() std::cout << '[' << std::invoke(&LoggableComponent::get_current_logger_name, self) << "] "

class A : public LoggableComponent {
public:
    A() : LoggableComponent("A") {}

    void foo() {
        auto self = this;
        LOG() << "foo()\n";
    }

    
    void bar(this auto&& self) {
        LOG() << "bar() explicit\n"; //works now 
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    a.foo();    
    a.bar();
}

Working demo
The output of the above program is:
[A] foo()
[A] bar() explicit


Method 2
You can also avoid using std::invoke altogether by having auto &self = *this; as shown below:
#define LOG() std::cout << '[' << self.get_current_logger_name() << "] "

class A : public LoggableComponent {
public:
    A() : LoggableComponent("A") {}

    void foo() {
        auto &self = *this; //now this will work without std::invoke
        LOG() << "foo()\n";
    }

    
    void bar(this auto&& self) {
        LOG() << "bar() explicit\n";  
    }
};

Working demo

Good idea, but this violates the rule "don't touch class A". As a user of the logging framework, I don't want to create extra variables before writing logs.

@Mikhail I think this could be the best that could be done here. This answer involves minimal changes to A. Maybe it is impossible to do this without making any changes to A.

BTW, with auto& self = *this;, you don't need std::invoke, self.get_current_logger_name() would do the job.

@Jarod42 Updated. Added it as method 2.
